# Async controller action with loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await

How would I go about writing an async controller action that is made up of 1 +n async calls (`await`)? E.g. let's pretend I need to retrieve the object `Foo` first and it has a variable number of `Bars` identifier and I need to fetch all those entities (for the sake of this question, there is no `fetchBarsByFooId`. Would I use `Task.WaitAll` or maybe `Parallel.For`?

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> Bars(int id) {
    Foo foo = await this.FooProvider.GetFooAsync(id);
    var bars = new ConcurrentQueue<Bar>();

    // Sub-optimal version
    foreach (int barId in foo.BarIDs) {
        Bar bar = this.BarProvider.GetBar(barId);
        bars.Enqueue(bar)
    }

    // Fetch each bar asynchronously and pass them to the view.
    ....

    return View(bars.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the first thing to work out is whether you actually want parallelism, or just asynchrony. Just asynchrony is simple:

```
var bars = new List<Bar>();
foreach (var id in foo.Bars)
{
    bars.Add(await BarProvider.GetBarAsync(id));
}
return View(bars);
```

For parallelism, you could use [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766.aspx):

```
var tasks = foo.Bars.Select(id => BarProvider.GetBarAsync(id));
var bars = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
return View(bars);
```

(I realize this is shorter code than the non-parallel version - but it's more conceptually tricky.)

You should *not* use `Parallel.For` or `Task.WaitAll` as both of those are *blocking* calls - whereas `Task.WhenAll` returns you a task which will complete when all the subtasks have completed.

Comment: I will try this out on the train home tonight before accepting your answer but this looks good.

Comment: Sorry about the delay, it took me a while to port all the codebase to the Task Parallel Library. This works great!

Comment: @Oli: Excellent :) Async/await really rocks :)